# Elastic Search fetch records if matched the multiple fields with different values in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below documents in ElasticSearch

```
[
    {
      "class": " Grade 1",
      "subject": [
        "Mathematics",
        "German",
        "Geometry",
        "Arts",
        "Physical Education"
      ],
      "student": [
        {
          "name": "George",
          "id": "ORT-823FT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Travis",
          "id": "ORT-873FT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott",
          "id": "ORT-883FT"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "class": " Grade 2",
      "subject": [
        "Mathematics",
        "German",
        "Geometry",
        "French",
        "Arts",
        "Physical Education"
      ],
      "student": [
        {
          "name": "Gibbs",
          "id": "ORT-923DG"
        },
        {
          "name": "Elizabeth",
          "id": "ORT-973DG"
        },
        {
          "name": "Michale",
          "id": "ORT-983DG"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I need to fetch the document only when the student name and id are matching, for eg: if the student name is George and the id is ORT-823FT, then the first document should be returned. On the other hand if the student name is Gibbs and the id is ORT-923DG then second document must be returned.

The below query works for me but is there  better way to write ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "student.id": "ORT-823FT"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "student.name": "George"
          }
        }
      ]
      
      , "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated**

The mapping for student is as below, I have added *"type": "nested",* as explained in the document.

```
{
  "student": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "studentResidence": {
        "properties": {
          "residenceAddress": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "phoneNumber": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "parentEmail": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "studentParentRelationShip": {
        "properties": {
          "relationshipType": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "residenceAddress": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "validFor": {
        "properties": {
          "endDateTime": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "startDateTime": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The corresponding query for the same is:

```
  {
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "student",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "student.id": "ORT-823FT"
                }},{
                "match": {
                  "student.name": "George"
                }
                
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am still getting an incorrect output. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, Below mapping should work, note I created `nested` only for `student` property and rest properties are normal.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "class": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "student": {
                "type": "nested", --> note this
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "subject": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you index the sample documents that you provided in your question+  below one more sample to test it properly.

```
{
    "class": " Grade 2",
    "subject": [
        "Mathematics",
        "German",
        "Geometry",
        "French",
        "Arts",
        "Physical Education"
    ],
    "student": [
        {
            "name": "Gibbs",
            "id": "ORT-abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elizabeth",
            "id": "ORT-973DG"
        },
        {
            "name": "Michale",
            "id": "ORT-983DG"
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "id": "ORT-923DG"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now same search query that your provided will return the proper results.

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "student",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "student.id": "ORT-823FT"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "student.name": "George"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SR

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "nested_mapping_student",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 4.0313807,
                "_source": {
                    "class": " Grade 1",
                    "subject": [
                        "Mathematics",
                        "German",
                        "Geometry",
                        "Arts",
                        "Physical Education"
                    ],
                    "student": [
                        {
                            "name": "George",
                            "id": "ORT-823FT"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Travis",
                            "id": "ORT-873FT"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Scott",
                            "id": "ORT-883FT"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I have re-looked at your suggestions, and I think the problem is its not performing an exact match, now lets imaging if we are looking for the name having George and the  id ORT-823FT, it will even list out the records like George Louis, Geroge Lduwig, George Phili. The other shocking aspect is these records are fetched despite the id's being different i.e. its not ORT-823FT.

Comment: @User27854, so in your case actually you need to do the exact match, its easy, just use the `.keyword` against both fields like `name.keyword` and `id.keyword`, if you generated mapping according to what I provided as Elasticsearch by default for every text fields creates a keyword subfield also

Answer (score 1):

what you did is not correct as you are not using the [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to store your student information, hence relationship between id and name is lost, this is very well explained in [this official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects).

You can also try it by indexing below document

```
{
    "class": " Grade 2",
    "subject": [
        "Mathematics",
        "German",
        "Geometry",
        "French",
        "Arts",
        "Physical Education"
    ],
    "student": [
        {
            "name": "Gibbs",
            "id": "ORT-abc"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elizabeth",
            "id": "ORT-973DG"
        },
        {
            "name": "Michale",
            "id": "ORT-983DG"
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "id": "ORT-923DG"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And see this is also coming in the query of `Gibbs` and id `ORT-923DG` which shouldn't be the case.**

**You need to use the [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to get your expected results in all cases.**

Comment: Sorry, for the delayed response, I did not get what you meant by see this is also coming in the query of Gibbs and id ORT-923DG which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I am new to elastic search, I shall go through the nested query and ask if I have any more queries on it.

Comment: @User27854 sure, thats the way to go, feel free to ask more queries, we are here to help you :)

Comment: As mentioned in the documents, I have updated the mapping by setting type as nested for student and am using a different query for it. Still the result is incorrect. You can see those changes in the update section of the question. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: @User27854 I think your mapping is not created properly, I am updating answer with my mapping and I tried on your sample data and it works perfectly fine :)